# Are we different or same?

Tags: social-psychology, psychology, genetics, behavioural-neuroscience

I don't know if this is the right site to ask this, if not sorry for that I am new here......

I am wondering if two childs from different parents from different regions are kept in a completely empty room, do they behave same or different and for why(for the genes? and they are just children, like pure children without any experience because if it will not they must behave differently for environmental experiences, right?)?
And if they behave in a same way, what if we make a huge area with every needs of living, an ideal environment to grow in the same way then everyone will learn the equal things and experiences so nothing wrong will happen.(like a utopia)
And I am thinking this to do with a medium number of people. If I do this with a large number of people will anomalies happen?
If they are not equal then there must be the factor genes will come to show the features but if the environment is right then will not the features work in a same manner?

If my question sounds silly, sorry......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Psychology.SE.

When you ask

> if two childs from different parents from different regions are kept in a completely empty room, do they behave same or different

that is a question which is heavily debated in Psychology. It all boils down to the [nature vs nurture or nature vs environment](https://www.simplypsychology.org/naturevsnurture.html) shaping behaviour.

Your question is definitely not silly and as it stands, the answer is very much open to opinion but you can get some information on the debate from the link provided above.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_versus_nurture
- https://behavioralscientist.org/the-end-of-nature-versus-nurture/
- https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/psychpedia/nature-versus-nurture
- https://www.softschools.com/examples/science/nature_vs_nurture_examples/482/
- https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-nature-versus-nurture-2795392

Comment: Thank u very much,